# C# Xamarin Timer Class Not Updating View

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TimerTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        Label label;
        int i = 0;
        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            label = new Label
            {
                Text = ""+i,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };
            this.Content = label;
            SetTimer();
            //this.Content = label;
            

        }
        public void SetTimer()
        {
            // Create a timer with a two second interval.
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
            // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private async  void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            i++;
            label.Text = ""+i;
            //this.Content = label;
        }
    }
}
```

I have followed [Microsoft's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2) definition for implementing the timer method, however, When trying to actually implement it, nothing is ever updated to the screen.

Below I have set up a simple program in Xamarin.Forms that should update the `label` to the count of whatever `i` is every `2 seconds`, however, the screen just sits at 0 (what the `label` was initiated to).

Does anyone have any understand what I am doing wrong and how to fix my issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not on the UI thread as the Timer callback is on a background thread, use `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` when updating UI elements in that case:

So when updating your `label` instance in the callback, do this:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => label.Text = "" +i;);
```

> If I were to update the text and update another element, would I just place a , after label.Text = ""+1or would I have to have a whole other line replicated,

The parameter provided to `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` is an `Action`, so you can execute as much code as needed on the UI thread using just one "block":

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    ...;
    ...;
    ...;
});
```

Or:

```
void UIThreadAction()
{
    ...;
    ...;
    ...;
}
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(UIThreadAction);
```

Comment: Hi @SuchiHangover, great! Thank you for that, I'll do some reading up on that, I do have a question regarding the line above. If I were to update the text and update another element, would I just place a `,` after `label.Text = ""+1`or would I have to have a whole other line replicated, for instance, `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => button.text = "click me";);`

Comment: @JerodFexlet See my answer update for an answer to that. 