# Lablel.Text will only update once

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm running a timer and counting time. Timer starts with a button and label shows the time. At least that was the plan.
But running the code, label.Text will only update once. It starts from 6:00 and will tick once to 5:59 and then will freeze why is this happening?

I spent so much time trying to understand what is going on. The variable time is changing, while the label.Text does not. Am I doing something wrong?

```
public partial class Running : ContentPage
{
    Timer timer;
    double seconds = 360;

    public Running()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button_run.Clicked += Button_Run_Clicked;
    }

    void Button_Run_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button_run.Text == "Start!")
        {
            button_run.Text = "Stop";
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 100; // 100 milliseconds  
            timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
            timer.Start();
        }

        else
        {
            button_run.Text = "Start!";
        }


    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        seconds -= 0.1;
        int minutes = (int)seconds / 60;
        int secs = (int)seconds % 60;
        string time = minutes.ToString() + ":" + secs.ToString();
        label_timer.Text = time; // the string time is changing!

        if (minutes != 0)
        {
            timer.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53789484/4984832

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UI updates can only be done on the main thread

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => {
  label_timer.Text = time;
});
```